# google private iCal : limiting date-range not working

Tags: api, icalendar

I'm using a private iCal url to retrieve a google calender.

I now try to limit the date-range in order to limit data. 
I tried this by adding parameters in the url
I've tried timeMin/timeMax as well as time-min and time-max, as well as other suggestions I found. But I keep getting ALL items.

Tried formats

> https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/my@mail.com/private-mykey/full?start-min=2006-03-16T00:00:00&start-max=2006-03-24T23:59:59

and

> https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/my@mail.com/private-mykey/full?singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&timeMin=2014-01-01T00:00:00&timeMax=2018-03-24T23:59:59

as suggested here and here

Comment: Sorry, but I had to remove the 'here'  links, because stackoverflow limited me to only use 2 links. The 'here' refers to other stackoverflow articles, so you can easily find them